# Make a Q promise function call blocking in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, synchronization, promise, q

In an angular service, we're exposing a function which provides a token and should be blocking, until the token is loaded.

the critical part in the service

```
....
    function getToken(){
        tokenPromise().then(
            function(token){ return token;},
            function(error){ return null;}
    }
....
```

**How do I turn this to a blocking function code?**

so that `service.getToken();` is blocking/synchronious until token is there.

Returning a promise/callback is not a solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, there're no *blocking functions* unless they're synchronous.

What you can do is returning the promise in `getToken` and continue it using promises with `then`:

```
getToken().then(function(token) {
    // Do stuff when I get the token
});
```

### About the last update of OP...

> Returning a promise/callback is not a solution.

**This can't be decided by you**. JavaScript can't block browser's UI thread, thus, your desired approach is absolutely impossible for now.

Comment: so in this case, how to make it synchronous? because returning a promise does not solve the problem.

Comment: @MemLeak If you're performing an AJAX request, there's no chance to make it synchronous. AJAX is "Asynchronous JavaScript and XML", check the *asynchronous* part :(

Comment: @MemLeak Returning the promise, solves the problem. Why not? The point is you need to leverage asynchronous programming or you're dead! :D

Comment: @MemLeak It's my advise... don't get me wrong. UI and asynchronocity today is a *must have*. You want non UI tasks to don't freeze the UI, don't you?

Comment: Because it shifts the problem to the next layer. nothing against async programming. this issue we have with waiting for the token showed up surprisingly ;)

Comment: @MemLeak That sounds like you should invest the work to restructure your code to work asynchronously

Comment: @MemLeak So you need to re-think your code :( JS won't provide a silver bullet here